# Python module scrapy always gives Traceback Error

Tags: python, scrapy, traceback

I have some problems with scrapy (http://scrapy.org/), actually it doesn't work. I installed it using

```
pip install scrapy
```

on a Windows System with python 3.4.3 installed (with Anaconda3), everything worked fine. It's Scrapy-1.0.5.

Then I tried to do the tutorial, but already the first command failed:

```
scrapy startproject tutorial
```

gives the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-17.1.1-py3.4.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 651, in _build_master
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-17.1.1-py3.4.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 952, in require
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-17.1.1-py3.4.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 844, in resolve
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (pyasn1 0.1.7 (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('pyasn1>=0.1.8'), {'pyasn1-modules'})

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-17.1.1-py3.4.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3084, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-17.1.1-py3.4.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3070, in _call_aside
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-17.1.1-py3.4.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3097, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-17.1.1-py3.4.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 653, in _build_master
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-17.1.1-py3.4.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 666, in _build_from_requirements
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-17.1.1-py3.4.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 844, in resolve
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (pyasn1 0.1.7 (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('pyasn1>=0.1.8'), {'pyasn1-modules'})
```

Any ideas about whats wrong here or how to fix it?

I tried out to uninstall and reinstall scrapy, nothing changed. Also tried to update it using

```
pip install -U scrapy
```

which failes with the error message

```
Command "C:\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\meyer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-5zv6_xhq\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\meyer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-mfxl3hbe-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\meyer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-5zv6_xhq\lxml
```

Actually, I have no idea whats the problem here. It looks like the python parser modules doesnt work here.

Calling Scrapy without any arguments gives the same error message.

Comment: Don't write that you solved the question, mark your answer as accepted once it's possible.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the hint and sorry for that. I will do as you said, but atm I cannot mark the answer. Dont know if it's because of my low reputation...

Comment: You need to wait two days if I recall correctly to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just investigated the problem:
Scrapy doesn't support Python 3.4., only Python 2.7.

I could delete this post but maybe someone else in the future will be as dumb as I was and this may help then.

Thanks and sorry.

Comment: Right, scrapy supports Python 3 only starting from 1.1 (yet to be released, 1.1rc1 available on PyPI)